# msvcr100.dll is missing - how to make executable backwards compatible

Tags: c++, dll

I have to make a presentation of my programm tomorow. I used Visual Studio 2010, but the presentation pc is my university labs pcs witch have vs 2008. I can't install anything on them. The language is c++, opengl

Can I make my executable backwards compatible or should I rely on my 8 years old laptop? 
I hate it if I have to use it cause the project is opengl and the frame rates I get are low...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rebuild your application using static linking rather than dynamic linking.

The problem you currently have is because your are linking to the runtime dynamically and it is not installed on the target machine. Statically linking the runtime sidesteps the issue. Note that dynamic linking is to be preferred for deployed software, but for the sake of your current predicament, static linking is the expedient solution.

The setting can be found under: Project | Properties | Configuration Properties | C/C++ | Code Generation | Runtime Library. Change this setting to **Multi-threaded (/MT)**.

Comment: Thanks so much! It's the first time I develop with VS, do you know where I can change this this?

Comment: I already added that to the answer in a grace period edit. I'm looking at VS2008 so it may be slightly different in 2010, but I expect you'll find it from what I say above.

Comment: Thanks it's the same path! That gave me an idea is it possible to do the same with some other dlls?
Right now in order for the executable to run glut.dll has to be in the same folder, can I add this to the executable? Sorry I know this is a completely different question

Comment: You would need to have a .lib file suitable for static linking. I don't know if the opengl code is available in such a form but I rather imagine it would be. And yes, this is another question!  ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can copy the missing .dll over next to the .exe file to get it up and running.
Or you can install the Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package (x86)    http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=5555

You can use Dependncy Walker to find other missing .dlls http://www.dependencywalker.com/